# How can I tell TypeScript that my property can either be a boolean OR a function with a specific signature?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following line in a `TypeScript` definition:

```
interface MyOptions {          
     public highlightMatch?: (instance: MyInstance, rendered: JQuery<HTMLElement>) => void;
}
```

Based on this, `TypeScript` knows that for my `highlightMatch` property, I am expecting a function with the given signature, which will not return anything. How could I tell `TypeScript`, that this same property, could also be a `boolean` value?

I tried this, but this isn't working:

```
public highlightMatch?: boolean | (instance: MyInstance, rendered: JQuery<HTMLElement>) => void;
```

Comment: `highlightMatch?: boolean | ((instance: MyInstance, rendered: JQuery<HTMLElement>) => void)` - wrap it in brackets

Comment: @VLAZ hmm, that seems to work, but if I do it this way, I lose my IntelliSense autosuggestion when trying to define the property as a function. Is this the only way to do this?

Comment: I don't know know which editor you use - I tend to try things out in the TypeScript playground online and neither definition gives me intellisense suggestions while typing. [Both give me the parameters types if I hover over](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=45&pln=8&pc=53#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAHMwD2IAzgIzIDeyV1NAUDQBbADmDANiw2KnGAgwH4AXMgBG+fGwhwQyAD7IAFItBEwMpCIDKYKKGYAaZFAggAJtAhmRACQAqqADIBRKQFtTYAJTIAvAD5kADd8YDMvWgBfWlBIWEQUDBw8QiIAJgoaLOR6aiZWDlZuXn5hJVV1EE1kHT0QQ2NTCxNrZHsnVwgPcB8A4NCzKNoEVLBkOBEk3AJiMl9M-PZOYr4GEUUADyN0XsDKSORokeIx0UmsadSM+cpFwq4eVfWt5B2-PcPIoA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend to do that. You will be doing a lot of checks to know if your property is of one type or the other.

Also keep in mind

```
// this will be always true if it contains `true` or a function
if(this.highlightMatch) {}
```

That said, You can warp it on an Type

```
interface MyInstance {
    x : any
}

type SomeFunction = (instance: MyInstance, rendered: JQuery<HTMLElement>) => void;
type BooleanOrFunction = boolean | SomeFunction

interface MyOptions {          
    highlightMatch: BooleanOrFunction;
}

const myOptionsWithBoolean: MyOptions = {
    highlightMatch: true,
}

const myOptionsWithFunction: MyOptions = {
    highlightMatch: (instance: MyInstance, rendered: JQuery<HTMLElement>) => {
        return void 0;
    },
}

myOptionsWithFunction.highlightMatch; // Typescript has No idea what this is 

if (myOptionsWithFunction.highlightMatch && typeof myOptionsWithFunction.highlightMatch !== 'boolean') {
    myOptionsWithFunction.highlightMatch(x as any, y as any);
} else {
    myOptionsWithFunction.highlightMatch // Here this is a boolean
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=29&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CSIDOY4hLIDeAUMhcgB7IBcyB6pAvqaWOgA4oDKA9gFsIAMQCuhMMD4hkAXmQAKUHgJJ6GbCsIQANMigQQAE2gQj9AFIBFUdHQAeABIAVVABkAogBsIQ8AD4ASjl-ZAA3PmAjAG52LhQAIT4%20HwIAeSgxCSkZeQAjZNSZAB9kfiEshElpNlBIWEQUDDTOatwSSk7KckoAC2AAc16vQd6wVDgwBF76JJSIdMzxKpzY1lIEaTxkAXQWtpwAdWAwXrmi9T3WnJw5Eh6KfqGRofHJ6fowKFsdFjZN3BgHZXA7HU6VNqXfY3O5kTpPYajN5TGaKZT4bSXTQYpB6AzGUzmZDWWxQBwudzeXyGMBBEL3LqUAxgURQGQRKLIAAMsU6zF%206120K2YN6EJyADoES8xhMUdFkAB6RXIZzxHAIKDAVrIXpwW4AOT4yCiC2QAHc9UDTsBbrbkLUYIohdcRScxcs2lLRjLkdNkAAyAPIDjcPhOl2g93i6Te55IuX%20gCEsnkAHICvMCGngnDKJGbqKYyA44jXonegoaPqGCB0Hp0AxboxAmtkBAvDgUHmKAW3eDPZLpQn3r0lSrHKYQ-07c3kJmin8gA)

My recommendation? Do it with Generics

```
interface MyInstance {
    x : any
}

type SomeFunction = (instance: MyInstance, rendered: JQuery<HTMLElement>) => void;
type HighlightMatch = boolean | SomeFunction

interface MyOptions<T> {          
    highlightMatch: T;
}

const myOptionsWithBoolean: MyOptions<boolean> = {
    highlightMatch: true,
}

const myOptionsWithFunction: MyOptions<SomeFunction> = {
    highlightMatch: (instance: MyInstance, rendered: JQuery<HTMLElement>) => {
        return void 0;
    },
}

myOptionsWithFunction.highlightMatch; // This is a function Thanks Generic! 
myOptionsWithBoolean.highlightMatch; // This is boolean!
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=57#)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @VLAZ, you can surround the signature of the method using parentesis or, to keep it more clean, you can define a custom type.

In this way, if you need to assign the method signature to some var it will be more easy and clean:

```
type MyFunction = (instance: MyInstance, rendered: JQuery<HTMLElement>) => void;
interface MyOptions {          
 public highlightMatch?: boolean | MyFunction;
}
```

All the other times you need to refer to that function, you can just use

```
let myVar: MyFunction;
```